# How to fix 'unused argument' with rasch model in R

Tags: r

I'm using the rasch model found in the ltm library and it asks for a constraint as one of it's arguments, i try to define that my constraint is 1 (which i assume means that my discriminant is 1) and when i run the code i get an "unused argument" error which shows the whole constraint.

```
    rasch(dep, constraint = cbind(ncol(dep) + 1, 1))
```

I've tried moving the argument into a new variable

```
    disc <- cbind(ncol(LSAT) + 1, 1)
```

which only causes a new error after just one run

```
    cycle k= 1 
    Error in if (abs(deltab) < convb) { : 
    missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
    In addition: Warning messages:
    1: In mean.default(b) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning 
    NA
    2: In if (abs(deltab) < convb) { :
    the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```